# Returning only files from the given folder path and excluding child folders - AWS S3

Tags: amazon-s3, .net-core

I have a folder called foo in aws S3.Inside the foo folder there are .csv files but there are also folders inside the foo folder. Is there anyway to exclude the folders inside the foo folder and only retrieve the csv files using .net core ?.

An Example would be:

```
Pull --> Parent Folder
Pull/test1.csv --> Child file
Pull/Bar --> Child folder
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try use[Directory.GetFiles()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=net-5.0#system-io-directory-getfiles(system-string-system-string))

```
   try
    {
        // Only get files that begin with the letter "c".
        string[] dirs = Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\", "c*");
        Console.WriteLine("The number of files starting with c is {0}.", dirs.Length);
        foreach (string dir in dirs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dir);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The process failed: {0}", e.ToString());
    }
```